# "Connection refused" error on socket_connect in php

Tags: php, perl, sockets

I am trying to convert some code from perl to php.

Perl code looks like below:

`my $handle = Connect($port, $host);`

and I am trying to use socket to do the same thing in php.
I have tried socket_create and socket_connect,
socket_create and socket_bind, and fsocketopen.

As a result, I'm stuck with error messages saying "Connection refused" or "permission denied":

> socket_connect() [function.socket-connect]: unable to connect [111]: Connection refused in

I am not sure if this is the problem I need to solve, or the problem of permission because the code in perl works fine (I did not write that code).

my php code looks like below:

```
$socket =  socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
if(!$socket){
        die('Error: socket_create()');
}
if(!socket_connect($socket,$host,$port)) {
        die('Error: socket_connect()');
}
```

I'm not the one who manages the server, so I will need to ask someone else for the access if it is a permission issue. What should I ask for specifically?

Or should I use some other function to connect to the server? I am new to perl, so I am not sure if socket_connect is the equivalent function to use or not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your perl code is able to establish the connection, no additional permissions should be needed to do the same in php. *Connection refused* means the remote host doesn't let you in (you probably connect to wrong address/port). *Permission denied* is more surprising, a lot of people have this kind of problem while running httpd scripts with SELinux enabled. If you're one of them, refer to the SELinux manpage:

> SELinux policy can be setup such that httpd scripts are not allowed to connect out to the network. This would prevent a hacker from breaking into you httpd server and attacking other machines. If you need scripts to be able to connect you can set the httpd_can_network_connect boolean on:
>
> setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1

I have a few concers to your examples though. `Connect` from your Perl snippet doesn't seem to be the standard socket connect; I don't know which module it belongs to, but are you sure there is no magic behind the call? As `socket_connect` takes address in dotted-quad notation (for IPv4), make sure you're not passing a hostname (you would need to make a DNS lookup first). At the very end check if it's really a TCP socket you need, not UDP.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Connect was a helper function, not the standard socket connect function. I didn't get to make a correct connection yet, but I will keep trying and your answer will be very helpful. Thanks again.

Comment: @user1507925 happy to help, post us some more details if you can't solve the problem.