# Connection refused error in PHP

Tags: php, sockets, port, host, minecraft

> [06-Nov-2013 17:57:32] PHP Warning:  socket_connect() [function.socket-connect]: unable to
>   connect [111]: Connection refused in
>   /home2/whoop/public_html/phptesting/main.php on line 43

I keep getting this error. This is a snippet of code in my main.php

```
<?php

$host = '76.72.172.166';
$port = 25608;

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP); //Create the socket
$connected = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port);//Try and connect
?>
```

I am trying to setup a minecraft player list this is what im using
http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/web-constantly-updated-website-widgets.148592/

Comment: Your code is all good, it may be an error with the server, perhaps a firewall or it's not been configured correctly?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Connection refused" error on socket\_connect in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370312/connection-refused-error-on-socket-connect-in-php)

Comment: try `telnet 76.72.172.166 25608` from the same user that runs php script

Comment: If you have command line access to the server try to `ping 76.72.172.16` to see if you can get to that IP and if so `telnet 76.72.172.16 25608` to make sure you can get to that port.

Comment: @doublesharp: "if you can get to that IP" --- ping availability does not mean anything in this case. ICMP may be disabled and port still available. The opposite is true as well.

Comment: @doublesharp: so what does it mean (from some TCP port availability perspective)?

Comment: @doublesharp: "On the other hand, I cannot get to that port" --- so how ping was helpful to realize that? :-) "assuming chargers2143 sees the same thing" --- there is a chance `76.72.172.166` allows connections from a particular subnet/IP(s) only.

Comment: The ping is working for me as well

Comment: @doublesharp: "Because if he can't get to the IP" --- what exactly "get to the IP" means? ICMP is not related to TCP 25608 in any way. So checking one has nothing in common with the other.

Comment: @doublesharp: "ICMP is generally open more than another random port" --- so what? `telnet` output would provide **everything** you need to continue the research. I still don't see how ping's results (either successful or not) would shed any light to the issue. PS: do you realize that ICMP route may be different from TCP 25608?

Comment: @doublesharp: have you tried to read the output? It states that explicitly. I understand that reading is boring and I used to arguing with people that barely can read a single line, but please do me a favour before you write your next answer here. Thank you.

Comment: @doublesharp: so? What do you think it means?

Comment: @chargers2143 sorry for all the internet arguing... i just tried to telnet again to your IP/port and it worked so you might want to give a shot, they could have just been down for a bit.

Comment: It's still not working. Could it be a firewall issue like the first comment said? Or are you aware of any other things to try? Thanks for all the help so far.

Comment: I tried this with other Minecraft server IP's and it still has the same error.

Comment: It is not recommended to post actual IP addresses, as this can lead to hacks on the server listed.

Answer (score 2):

Try as a UDP connection

```
$host = '76.72.172.166';
$port = 25608;

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP); //Create the socket
$connected = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port);//Try and connect
```